# Meteor.js - mongodb - Leaflet.js - geo query from client to server - $within $box refresh - stack call size exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, leaflet, geojson

So I have a Meteor.js project with a 'server' and a 'client' folders. In there I have a leaflet.js map.

Inside server.js I have a query to only show markers within a certain bounding box. This works fine. I am trying to update this marker when a map is moved to encompass the map's bounding box.

in **./server/server.js** I have some startup methods:

```
 Meteor.startup(function () {

     Meteor.methods({

        buildCollections: function() {

             Locations = new Meteor.Collection('locations');
             Locations._ensureIndex({'geometry.coordinates':'2dsphere'});
        },
        testStub: function(tst) {
            console.log("test stub");
            return tst;
        },
        showBoundingBox: function(mapBox) {
            return Locations.find({
                    'geometry.coordinates': {
                        $within:{
                            $box:mapBox
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    });

    Meteor.call('buildCollections');

 });
```

The **showBoundingBox** method is called by the server on publishing the collection:

```
Meteor.publish('locations', function() {

           mapBox= [ [151.190,-33.94]
                ,[151.2,-33.84]] ;
            return   Meteor.call('showBoundingBox',mapBox);

});
```

This all works ok until I want to sent a different bounding box based on the map bounding box when the Leaflet map has been moved:

So in my **./client/client.js** I want to call the server method to update the visible markers so I call the server method:

```
window.map.on('moveend', function(e) {


   var b = window.map.getBounds();

   var bounds=[[b._southWest.lng,
        b._southWest.lat],
        [b._northEast.lng,
        b._northEast.lat]
        ];

        Meteor.call('testStub',"echoing back to the client",
        function(error,result){

        if(error)
        {
        console.log(error.reason);
        }else
        {
        console.log(result);
        }

        });


        Meteor.call('showBoundingBox',bounds,
        function(error,result){

        if(error)
        {
        console.log(error.reason);
        }else
        {
        console.log(result);
        }

        });


  });
```

Now the **testStub** method returns the string back to the client, but the **showBoundingBox** method crashes Meteor with the error:

```
 Internal exception while processing message{ msg: 'method',
 method: 'showBoundingBox',
 params: [ [Object], [Object] ] ],
 id: 'n' } Maximum call stack size exceeded undefined
```

Where n is an incremented numerical index.

I am trying to update the **$within** query to a new set of coordinates when a map has been moved. Is this a legitimate bug? Is there another way I can achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Make a bug report I suggest.

Comment: Thanks Farid, I will do that. Apart from this way, is there another way to refresh a geo query in Mereor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work by being able to monitor the $within cursor using http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/48367809759/meteors-reactive-data-sources